# Isset works on Local server, but it doesn't on live server

Tags: php

I'm developing website on my local using Xampp v3.2.2, I'm running query for filtering my data, it works fine on my local but when I upload (updated my code on server) it always return 0 value.
My server using native php 5.6

I've already putting !empty instead isset, but it's not working. So here's one of my filter's code:

```
    $this->_require_login();
    $user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $cust = $this->input->post('cust_name');
    $dtstart = new DateTime($this->input->post('date_start'));
    $dtend = new DateTime($this->input->post('date_end'));
    $start_date = $dtstart->format('Y-m-d ');        
    $end_date = $dtend->format('Y-m-d ');        


    if ((isset($cust) && !empty($cust)) && (isset($start_date) && !empty($start_date)) && (isset($end_date) && !empty($end_date))){

        $this->db->select('t1.cust_name, t1.act_type, t1.act_detail, t1.date_added, t1.date_modified, t1.act_notes')
                ->from('activity as t1')
                ->join('user as t2', 't1.user_id = t2.user_id', 'LEFT')
                ->where('t1.cust_name', $cust)
                ->where('t2.user_id', $user)
                ->where('DATE(t1.date_added) >= ', $start_date)
                ->where('DATE(t1.date_modified) <= ', $end_date);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();                        

    if ($result) {
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
            'result' => 1,
            'data' => $query->result_array()
        ]));
        return false;            
    }
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
        'result' => 0,
        'error' => 'Could not find data.'
    ]));

    }
```

On my local it returns corresponding records, but on live server it returns 0.

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working" ? have you checked if the query is running but returns no results, or may be it's not running at all. have you checked the db error response? you have a lot of scenarios to debug.

Comment: I check form data, it sent. but it's always showing "Could not find data" / result => 0 right?

Answer (score 0):

You have no else statement:

```
<?php

if ((isset($cust) && !empty($cust)) && (isset($start_date) && !empty($start_date)) && (isset($end_date) && !empty($end_date))){

        $this->db->select('t1.cust_name, t1.act_type, t1.act_detail, t1.date_added, t1.date_modified, t1.act_notes')
                ->from('activity as t1')
                ->join('user as t2', 't1.user_id = t2.user_id', 'LEFT')
                ->where('t1.cust_name', $cust)
                ->where('t2.user_id', $user)
                ->where('DATE(t1.date_added) >= ', $start_date)
                ->where('DATE(t1.date_modified) <= ', $end_date);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();                        

    if ($result) {
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
            'result' => 1,
            'data' => $query->result_array()
        ]));
        return false;            
    }else{
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
            'result' => 0,
            'error' => 'Failed Query'
        ]));
    }
}else{
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
            'result' => 0,
            'error' => 'Values Not Set'
        ]));
}

?>
```

Also if that isn't a function putting `return false;` won't return anything and is probably why it's running all the way through.

Comment: I add else statement as you said, it still return no data. I wonder why it's working on my local but not on live

Comment: Then you most likely have an error in your SQL or its returning empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably rewrite your code including a `try/catch` and forcing errors to show. Don't forget that in live servers most of the errors are set to hidden. So, no obvious errors are shown to the end user.

**To debug**

```
try {
   //put your code hear
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   die('An exception :- '. $e->getMessage());
}
```

If that doesn't still bring you enough information to debug, add following lines to the beginning of the `php` file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Not to forget**, once you resolved your issue remove or comment out above three error reporting lines. Because you don't want to show internal errors to end users.

Hope this helps you to debug your problem.

Cheers.